# Stimul report does not show the report page

Tags: c#, stimulsoft

I'm using Stimul Report to create a report page. the report page shows correctly. but when I close the report page in the second time report does not show and it only shows a blank page.
when i close the form and then open it the report work correctly but only one time.
 I use code below in C#

```
report1.compile();
report1.show();
```

I'm also using Stimul 2012 and .Net4

Comment: 3 days waiting for answer

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
report1.compile();
report1.Render();
report1.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use twice

```
StimulsoftReport.compile()
```

Pre-try and inside try

ex:

```
Try
   Dim stiHeder As StiVariable = New StiVariable("Setings", "VarHeder", strHeder)
   StiIsSuing.Dictionary.Variables.Add(stiHeder)
   'StiIsSuing.Dictionary.Synchronize()
   StiIsSuing.Compile()
   StiIsSuing.Render()
   StiIsSuing.Show()
   'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox("Error show report" & vbNewLine & ex.Message)
End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save your report to file and then:

```
stiReport1.Load("Report.mrt");
stiReport1.Compile();
```

If you want to send a parameter:

```
stiReport1["faktorID"] = faktor_ID;
```

and then you should create a variable `:name=faktorID` in your report